# Grails - can't evaluate expression debugging in Eclipse inside annotated method

Tags: eclipse, grails

When I set a breakpoint in Eclipse doing `grails test-app`, evaluating expressions with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> fails inside an annotated method.  The error is complaining about not being able to resolve the annotation class.

The annotation itself is indicating an aspect, handled via AOP.

The method works normally, I just can't debug effectively in Eclipse.

How would I fix this?  Is this a bug in Eclipse or in Groovy?

This is the error I get from the Eclipse error logs:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
____Eval.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class com.mycompany..... 
@ line 4, column 60.
  ebapps....MyClass
                             ^

1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:313)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:1030)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:636)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:585)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.groovy.debug.core.evaluation.GroovyJDIEvaluator.convertSnippetToScript(GroovyJDIEvaluator.java:349)
at org.grails.ide.eclipse.groovy.debug.core.evaluation.GroovyJDIEvaluator.performEvaluate(GroovyJDIEvaluator.java:183)
```

Comment: Maybe related: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2482 and https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2329